# How to get HTML form values using Swift and Kanna Library

Tags: html, swift, forms

Say I have Web app wrapped in a UIWebview in Swift.  How can I retrieve the value of an input field, hidden or typed like below

```
<input type="text" name="code" value="Swift">
```

Using Swift and Kanna

Here is my code for getting an h2 tag that works fine. But I need to get input fields, especially hidden fields.

```
 func parseHtml(html: String) {
    if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        for node in doc.css("h2") {
            let value = node.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
            print("\(value)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an id to your input tag, you can always run a Javascript function
in your UIWebView to retrieve the value.

```
<input type="text" id= "codeId" name="code" value="Swift">

var inputValue = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('codeId').value")!
```